# Automatic selection of .o file in static library (.a file)

Tags: linux, static-libraries, ld

I'm developing a static library (libfb.a) file which contains multiple implementations of two functions:

- foo.c contains `void foo() { ... }`.
- bar.c contains `void bar() { ... }`.
- foobar.c contains `void foo() { ... }` and `void bar() { ... }`.

All the 3 implementations (`...`) are different, because if both *foo* and *bar* are needed, both of them can be implemented more efficiently, using each other.

How can I combine the .o files to an .a file for which GNU ld would do automatic selection, i.e. `gcc prog.c libfb.a` will

- use foo.o within libfb.a if prog.c calls *foo*, but not *bar*;
- use bar.o within libfb.a if prog.c calls *bar*, but not *foo*;
- use foobar.o with libfb.a if prog.c calls both *foo* and *bar*.

I was trying to do it using weak symbols and weak aliases, but it didn't work. Maybe it's not possible. Any ideas how it can be done?

Comment: This is not possible, you can't define symbols in terms of each other (e.g. change the linking when `prog.c` uses *both* symbols).
Plus, a static library is just a `.o` file collection [in an archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_(Unix)).

Comment: @A.Monti: It's indeed possible to solve this with only foo.c and foobar.c (no bar.c) using weak aliases and proper ordering of the .o files with the .a file. If that's possible, then maybe foo.c + bar.c + foobar.c is also possible.

Comment: Well, indeed you can use symbol weakness to define priorities, but you simply can't detect when "prog.c calls **both** foo and bar" using the available primitives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeating @A.Monti's comment as an answer.

It's not possible. You can't detect when *prog.c calls both foo and bar* using the available primitives.